# Multiple transactions in one block

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, full-node

There are three wallets A, B, C, wallet B is empty, I send one ether from wallet A to wallet B, and I want to send 1 ether from wallet B to wallet C in the same block, how can I implement this?
I know what is real, because I saw such transactions
I also have my bsc node

Answer (score 1):

##### Edit: BSC doesn't have flashbots, and I am not sure how it is done there.

For Ethereum, you can use a flashbots bundle:

```py
eth_sendBundle = {
  'jsonrpc': "2.0",
  'id': str or int,
  'method': "eth_sendBundle",
  'params': [{
    'txs': [str],               # Array[String], A list of signed transactions to execute in an atomic bundle       
    'blockNumber': str,         # String, a hex encoded block number for which this bundle is valid on       
    'minTimestamp': int,        # (Optional) Number, the minimum timestamp for which this bundle is valid, in seconds since the unix epoch       
    'maxTimestamp': int,        # (Optional) Number, the maximum timestamp for which this bundle is valid, in seconds since the unix epoch       
    'revertingTxHashes': [str], # (Optional) Array[String], A list of tx hashes that are allowed to revert       
    'replacementUuid': str,     # (Optional) String, UUID that can be used to cancel/replace this bundle 
  }]
}
```

Simply build the json object, sign it with a key created only for signing flashbots messages:

```py
def sign_flash(_tx_body: str) -> str:
  message = messages.encode_defunct(text=w3.keccak(text=_tx_body).hex()) 
  signature = f'{Account.from_key(FLA).address}:{w3.eth.account.sign_message(message, FLA).signature.hex()}'
  return signature
```

Then send directly to the flashbots endpoint:

```py
def send_flash(_request: dict) -> bytes:
  request = dumps(_request)
  headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Flashbots-Signature': sign_flash(request) }
  return post('https://relay.flashbots.net', data=request, headers=headers).content
```

https://docs.flashbots.net/flashbots-auction/searchers/advanced/rpc-endpoint/

Comment: do you know how this can be done on a bsc network? since flashbots only works on an eth network.

Comment: Don't know, probably same idea but private agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Yoo  Maka,

If you wanna do multiple Txn in an single block you can try doing that in Golang.

Its very simple with Golang  if its feasible for your project